A confusion about the series development of the complex function f(z)/g(x) in Ahlfors' book page 182
In the Taylor series section, he mentioned that in developing the general law for the coefficients of the Taylor series of the function $f(z)/g(z)$, which is the form below:
For instance, suppose that
\begin{align*}
f(z) &= a_o + a_1z + a_2z^2 + \cdots + a_n z^n + \cdots,\\
g(z) &= b_o + b_1z + b_2z^2 + \cdots + b_n z^n + \cdots.
\end{align*}
With an abbreviated notation, we write
\begin{equation*}
f(z) = P_n(z) + [z^{n+1}];\quad g(z) = Q_n(z) + [z^{n+1}].
\end{equation*}
, in which $g(0)=b_0\ne0$ and the symbol $[z^{n+1}]$ stands for any function which is analytic and has a zero of at least order $n+1$ at the origin, or less precisely, it denotes a function which contains the factor $z^{n+1}$. Then he concluded that by use of ordinary long division, continued until the remainder includes the factor $z^{n+1}$, we can determine a polynomial $R_n$ such that $P_n = Q_nR_n + [z^{n+ 1}]$. But from the division with remainder proposition in polynomial theory, the degree of the remainder should be less than the degree of $Q_n$.So, how does this mechanism work in the context of Ahlfors' statement?

When you edit that post to correct some words you should not accidentally delete a $ sign in front of $n+1$.

@Afntu do not approve edits that mess up mathjax.

Ok, I will take care of this in future.

It might be helpful to look at a specific example of a long division of power series to better see what's going on. Analytic functions $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k$ when expanded as power series have typically an infinite number of non-zero terms. To perform long division, we cannot start with a highest power with a non-zero coefficient, as this is not necessarily given. Instead we do long division by starting with the constant term.
Example: We consider a long-division of
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f(z)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+[z^5]}\\
\color{blue}{g(z)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1+z^2}=1-z^2+z^4+[z^5]}
\end{align*}
where we take $n=4$ and put all terms $z$ with power $\geq 5$ into $[z^5]$.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f(z):g(z)}&=\left(1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+[z^5]\right)\\
&\qquad : \left(1-z^2+z^4+[z^5]\right)\tag{1}\\
&\,\,{\color{blue}{=1}}+\left(z+2z^2+z^3+[z^5]\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad :\left(1-z^2+z^4+[z^5]\right)\tag{2}\\
&\,\,{\color{blue}{=1+z}}+\left(2z^2+2z^3+[z^5]\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad :\left(1-z^2+z^4+[z^5]\right)\tag{3}\\
&\,\,{\color{blue}{=1+z+2z^2}}+\left(2z^3+2z^4+[z^5]\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad :\left(1-z^2+z^4+[z^5]\right)\tag{4}\\
&\,\,{\color{blue}{=1+z+2z^2+2z^3}}+\left(2z^4+[z^5]\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad :\left(1-z^2+z^4+[z^5]\right)\tag{5}\\
&\,\,{\color{blue}{=1+z+2z^2+2z^3+2z^4}}+\left([z^5]\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad :\left(1-z^2+z^4+[z^5]\right)\tag{6}\\
\end{align*}
showing in (6) we still have $[z^5]$ covering all terms with powers $\geq 5$.
We get
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f(z)=\left(1+z+2z^2+2z^3+2z^4\right)g(z)+[z^5]}
\end{align*}
according to the book by Ahlfors.

Comment: We do the following calculations

(1): $\left(1+z+z^2+z^2+z^4+[z^5]\right)-(1)\times\left(1-z^2+z^4+[z^5]\right)$

(2): $\left(z+2z^2+z^3+[z^5]\right)-(z)\times\left(1-z^2+z^4+[z^5]\right)$

(3): $\left(2z^2+2z^3+[z^5]\right)-\left(2z^2\right)\times\left(1-z^2+z^4+[z^5]\right)$

(4): $\left(2z^3+2z^4+[z^5]\right)-\left(2z^3\right)\times\left(1-z^2+z^4+[z^5]\right)$

(5): $\left(2z^4+[z^5]\right)-\left(2z^4\right)\times\left(1-z^2+z^4+[z^5]\right)$


We can verify the calculation easily since
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}}&=\frac{1+z^2}{1-z}=\left(1+z^2\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k
\color{blue}{=1+z+2\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}z^k}
\end{align*}

Thanks! I was experimenting with some random polynomials the other day, but seldom thought about using geometric series and starting from the lowest terms. This is a very illuminating and helpful example!

@Guihuage: You're welcome. :-)
